# Calling a controller method from .cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mono

I want to call an action I've got in my controller class with a `Html.ActionLink` from my `index` page but I'm getting an error and can't understand why.

Can anyone help me?

The `Test` action in `HomeController.cs` is the action I want to call.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace ExchangeRazor.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index ()
        {
            var mvcName = typeof(Controller).Assembly.GetName ();
            var isMono = Type.GetType ("Mono.Runtime") != null;

            ViewData ["Version"] = mvcName.Version.Major + "." + mvcName.Version.Minor;
            ViewData ["Runtime"] = isMono ? "Mono" : ".NET";

            return View ();
        }


        public ActionResult Test()
        {

            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService ();
            //CREDENTIALS!//
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials ("*****@****.com", "******");
            service.Url = new Uri ("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
            service.TraceEnabled = true;
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;


            EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage (service);
            email.ToRecipients.Add ("********");
            email.Subject = "MacHallo";
            email.Body = new MessageBody ("Melding fra mac exchange webservices API");
            email.Send ();


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
            
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
<h2>Welcome to ASP.NET MVC @ViewData["Version"] on @ViewData["Runtime"]!</h2>

<button>@Html.ActionLink("Send", "Test")</button>
```

**Edit:**

> System.MissingMethodException
> Method not found: 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.get_AppendTrailingSlash'.
>
> Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
> Details: Non-web exception.
> Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.Mvc.

Comment: What error are you getting, and where?

Comment: Which part of the code? Xamarin isnt a language..

Comment: Where do you get this error message?

Comment: I think this is because you use Xamarin, which referenced to Mono instead of .NET. Although Mono can run MVC 5, it seems that it's lack "get_AppendTrailingSlash" on "RouteCollection". Therefore, any uri generation methods like Html.ActionLink, Html.Form, etc will throw this error. My suggestion is either stick with MVC 4, or switch to .NET entirely.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply do the following:

```
<form action="~/.../Test" method="post">
     <input type="submit" id="btnSend" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Please note, you'll need to map accordingly to your `Test` controller.

That would automatically trigger your content as a `form submit` assuming you have more information to submit.  This would then call your controller `Test`.  Your other approach would be to use `Ajax`, which you could also trigger a `post`.

Comment: [Perfect match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497900/method-routecollection-get-appendtrailingslash-not-found-when-using-razor-url/30561228#30561228)

Comment: @Zameeramir you don't do much web development if you haven't seen a simple form post.

Comment: Yeah, I accept that!!! :) I'm emphasizing that we tend to go extra geeky when we have simple enough solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Since your action `Test` is producing side effects I recommend using a `POST` instead of a `GET`.

Change the link to a form with a button.

```
<h2>Welcome to ASP.NET MVC @ViewData["Version"] on @ViewData["Runtime"]!</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
}
```

Then decorate the controller method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test() { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont have the opportunity to try at the moment, but you could try removing the [HttpPost].

Comment: A Controller should be decorated with some form of `Http` deceleration. Each controller correlates some state for the page, ie: `Get, Put, Delete, Post`

Comment: @Greg it seems as though this is a method inside a controller, could be wrong though.