# Method 'RouteCollection.get_AppendTrailingSlash' not found when using Razor Url helpers in ASP.NET MVC 5 Mono

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ubuntu, asp.net-mvc-5, mono

I am creating an [ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5) application in [Mono](http://mono-project.com) (Ubuntu 14.4, Monodevelop 5.9, Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.1).

I see that some of the razor components are not recognized, eg:

```
@Url.Action
```

When I add this

```html
<a title="Notifications" href="@Url.Action("_Listing","Home")"> Home </a>
```

I get this error:

> System.MissingMethodException
>
> Method 'RouteCollection.get_AppendTrailingSlash' not found.

`System.Web.Mvc` is referenced from the packages. Is there anything else which is required?

**Update:** I tried these solutions so far:

- [Does the Razor View Engine work for Mono?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239645/does-the-razor-view-engine-work-for-mono)
- [Is it possible to use Razor 2.0 view engine under mono?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566352/is-it-possible-to-use-razor-2-0-view-engine-under-mono?lq=1)
- http://www.davidloo.com/?p=479
- http://iws.io/walkthrough-porting-asp-net-mvc-website-to-mono-2-6-1-and-mysql-on-linux-apache-porting-to-mono-part-3-of-3/

It seems like it is a [known issue](https://github.com/chrisfcarroll/Mvc5-not-yet-working-on-mono) but I strongly believe there shall be some hack for this to work. I tried using aspx engine also but no gain.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you move the @Url.Action into javascript, for example: location.href = '@Url.Action("_Listing", "Home")';

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work . The same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest news afaik is that Miguel rejected my [minimal pull request last year](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/874) but you can see at the bottom of that Pull Request that a couple of others have got builds on github which include this and more.

I can't see anyone's got a pull request accepted for mono mainline. The way forward I can see is if you know/can persuade someone on the Xamarin team to push this.

Or, helping with getting the now-open-sourced .Net code running on mono.

But https://github.com/gentoo/dotnet looks interesting: It has pulled this and some other MVC5 changes.

Comment: The fix for this is currently on Master. They expect it to be in the 4.3 release. Not sure when that is going to be however.

Answer (score 1):

As of right now, the only way to get around this is to build and install Mono from source from GitHub.

You can refer to the Xamarin Bugzilla issue: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=16475#c13

But, then, you might end up running into something else.... This doesn't seem to be a high-priority for the Mono guys; rather, the Xamarin/mobile story seems to gain the most attention.

Comment: Thanks @realistchuckle - I tried that as well. Doesn't seems to be working. I'm trying to make MVC 4 atleast to work using [your](http://curtis.schlak.com/2014/02/04/setup-asp-net-mvc-4-on-monodevelop-4.2.html) blog but getting numerous issues.

Answer (score 0):

[The problem now seems to be resolved](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/58e0608c10c621b15fd9f396f8e46c567891b231).

**Meanwhile, I had used this simple hack:** Instead of using ASP.NET MVC helpers, We can use basic HTML syntax like this:

**For anchor like components:**

```html
<a href="~/ControllerName/ActionName"> Test </a>
```

**For form like components:**

```html
    <form action="~/ControllerName/ActionName">
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Test"/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

Surely, it doesn't solve the bug but at least it can get ASP.NET MVC 5 project running on Mono.

Thanks to [@teovankot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1849444/teo-van-kot) for pointing this out.