# Action and ActionLink not working on ASP.NET Mono Razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ubuntu, razor, mono

How to use hyper linking in Razor without `@Url.*` or `@Html.*`

There are 4 ways to **hyperly link** views in ASP.NET MVC as far as I know:

- `@Url.Action`
- `@Url.ActionLink`
- `@Html.Action`
- `@Html.ActionLink`

I can use them as, for example:

```
<a href=@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")> Test </a>
```

Which generates:

```
<a href="ControllerName/ActionName"> Test </a>
```

Is there a way to generate the Url part i.e. **"ControllerName/ActionName"** in ASP.NET MVC Razor apart from the above mentioned 4 ways?

**Background:** [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) is [not able to recognize these kind of Razor components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497900/how-to-use-razor-in-asp-net-mvc-5-mono). If some kind of Url generation works out then we can use ASP.NET MVC 5 with Razor on Mono.

Comment: All Url generation code goes through the same codepath at the end, so I doubt any existing methods using Route Table would work...If you can't rebuild Mono -  Consider reading the code and building your own helper that builds Url based on routing table/attributes.

Comment: You right @AlexeiLevenkov. I have the same doubt, but I just wanted to give it a try. Maybe if it works out. The last resort would be to make some kind of helper.

Comment: also you always can just write url without helpers.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Hey, you're a MS guy!!! Just one question - is MS billing Xamarin for making Mono ASP.NET MVC work on Linux. Mono MVC works best on Windows but on Linux it keep failing. What are MS's plans for it?

Comment: @teovankot - but how can I refer to an Action in a Controller? in Webforms it is pretty straightforward. e.g: `<a href="Folder/File.aspx"> Test </a>`

Comment: @zameeramir you already write it =) `href="ControllerName/ActionName"` that's how you reffer

Comment: @teovankot - many +1s for opening my eyes. But after clicking the anchor it demonstrates some strange behavior. I'm updating the question.

Comment: @zameeramir I have as much information as you can get about plans of other teams - whatever is publicly available on blogs :). (I'm also not particularly involved with  Xamarin, so I can't even recommend possible good source of info you are looking for).

Comment: There is no such method `@Url.ActionLink()` and `@Html.Action()` does not create a link (it calls a controller method to render a partial view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can always look up ASP.NET MVC source code, and copy what you need, if it is not implemented in mono yet.
Here you can find it: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/LinkExtensions.cs

But I've been using mono and ASP.NET MVC 4, and I had no problem like you.
Here is my code on github, it was running on mono and xsp.
https://github.com/rstraszewski/HomeCenter/tree/master/HomeCenter.Presentation

As you can see, for example in _Layout.cshtml, I was using Html.ActionLink...Although I was using windows and visual studio for compiling and developing, and mono only for runtime...

You can also create your own html helpers to generate links...
And there is also a Html.RouteLink helper method, which also can generate you a link.

Example of using Html.RouteLink:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Some link", "Default", new RouteValueDictionary(new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"}))
```

---

Yes, you can also use something like:

```
<a href="~/Home/Index">Some link</a>
```

Notice that the **~/** is important in the above snippet, without it the Url demonstrates a strange behaviour but you need to remember, that this will work, because this is how default routing is working... If you change default routing, this can not work.